# Regarding 'this' in callbacks in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, closures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JavaScript “this” keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword)

I am a bit confused about the callbacks used for `EventEmitter` 's in node.js.

```
var events = require("events");

function myObject() {
    this.name = "Test Object";
    this.x = 99;
    this.y = 100;
}

myObject.prototype = new events.EventEmitter();

var myobject = new myObject();

myobject.addListener('dbg1', function() {
    console.log("this.name = " + this.name);    //this.name gives the name not undefined
    console.log("myobject.name = " + myobject.name);        //so does this 
});

myobject.emit('dbg1');
```

Why is `this` inside the callback referring to  `myobject`? The closure for the callback function is the global scope in this code, am I right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scope is irrelevant for determining the value of `this`, that comes from the context. That is determined by how the function is called. The events module you load will call it in the context of `myobject`.

The [relevant code](https://github.com/Gozala/events/blob/master/events.js#L35) is:

```
listener.apply(this, args);
```

The first argument of [the `apply` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) is the context to use for calling the function (`listener`). You can trace it back to the object from there.

Comment: I see. So, node too calls the callback with by `apply` -ing it on the object? I am a newbie at node as well as javascript, so I guess this is the standard way events are implemented in every api?

Comment: It's the event library that does not, not node itself. There are various ways an event api could be implemented, almost everything will make `this` the object to which the event is bound though.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same for most of the node codebase. There was a small discussion about this a long time ago, and the consensus was that `.call(this)` entails too much overhead and was really ugly/annoying to put everywhere. So in other words, don't ever assume `this` is what you think.

edit: Nevermind, EventEmitter doesn't specifically apply in this case and I completely misread your question.

Comment: I strongly suspect that it's safe to assume that EventEmitter will always arrange for `this` to refer to the object that's the target of an event.

Comment: Well according to the code posted in Quentin's answer it definitely does.

Comment: @Pointy, yeah, I misread the question as a case of "`this` doesn't equal my object". My answer is very irrelevant (I was pointing out there are a lot of places in node and node modules where callbacks won't be invoked with a context). You're right though, EventEmitter::emit is not one of them.